# How to get a component/element provider injector within its node definition

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

tl;dr: During debug/development how can I can view a particular html element's provider injector or better yet its node definition.

So according to this [blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-curios-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular-582562abcf0a)

> Each view node is created using a node definition that holds metadata describing the node.
>
> In Angular, a node definition that describes an HTML element defines its own injector. In other words, an HTML element in a component’s template defines its own element injector. And this injector can populated with providers by applying one or more directives on the corresponding HTML element.
>
> The definition that Angular creates for this template includes the following metadata for the div element [*[See gist]*](https://gist.github.com/maximusk/902199c6eea4d44105ab356ff163374b#file-node-definition-ts)

How can i see my element's node definition in my app during debugging? ie in my Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following directive that adds a provider:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[provider]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'token',
            useValue: 'value'
        }
    ]
})
export class ProviderDirective {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Ptovider Dir');
    }
}
```

And use it in a template like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'a-comp',
    template: `
        <div provider>I am div with a provider</div>
    `
})
export class AComponent {}
```

To find the element definition and providers added by the directive, open a console, select the `div` element and type the following:

```
ng.probe($0).injector.elDef
```

There you'll see `element` property pointing to an object with public providers.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome dev-tools, during `ng serve` :

- inspect an element of the component you want to watch
- it will be highlighted in the dev tools `Elements` tab
- find the parent tag (usually `app-something`)
- click on it

Now, if you input `console.log($0)` in your console, it should display this element. Don't select another element, as you would loose the context of this component.

- input `const comp = ng.probe($0).componentInstance`

You now have a reference to your component.

I'm not sure you can have access to its injector unless you declare it as a dependency though.